# Batch emailing with Mailgun and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailgun, nodemailer

I'm using the Mailgun node.js module to send batch emails out.

According to the big yellow warning message in the [official docs](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#batch-sending), specifying recipient vars should result in sending "each recipient an individual email with only their email in the to field."

However, my recipients can see all of the "to" addresses. I am successfully using recipient-vars to set the email subject for users, so it does appear that these are being read in correctly.

Note that I am sending an HTML email using MIME. I tried this with the more straight-forward plain text variation, and it did appear to work.

Is anyone able to help me understand why my recipients can see all other recipients? Am I doing something wrong, or does this functionality not work for Mailgun MIME emails?

```
// recipients
var recipients = ['email1@email1.com', 'email2@email2.com', 'email3@email3.com'];
var recipientVars = {
    'email1@email1.com': {
        id: 1,
        subject: 'Subject 1'
    },
    'email2@email2.com': {
        id: 2,
        subject: 'Subject 2'
    },
    'email3@email3.com': {
        id: 3,
        subject: 'Subject 3'
    }
};

// options
var options = {
    from: 'Me <me@me.com>',
    to: recipients,
    'recipient-variables': recipientVars,
    subject: '%recipient.subject%',
    text: myMailText,
    html: myMailHTML,
    headers: {
        'X-Mailgun-Recipient-Variables': JSON.stringify(recipientVars)
    }
};

// create mail
var mail = new nodemailer(options);

// send mail
mail.compile().build((err, message) => {
    var mailData = {
        to: recipients,
        message: message.toString('ascii'),
        'recipient-variables': recipientVars
    };
    mailgun.messages().sendMime(mailData, (err, res) => {
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Seems this functionality doesn't work with `sendMime()` method, but it does with regular `send()` method even without any mail compilation. Here is working code snippet:

```
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({
  apiKey: 'api_key',
  domain: 'domain'
});

const recipients = ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com'];
const recipientVars = {
  'email1@gmail.com': {
    id: 1,
    subject: 'Subject 1',
    name: 'Name 1'
  },
  'email2@gmail.com': {
    id: 2,
    subject: 'Subject 2',
    name: 'Name 2'
  }
};

const envelope = {
  from: 'Sender <sender@gmail.com>',
  to: recipients,
  subject: '%recipient.subject%',
  html: 'Hey <strong>%recipient.name%<strong>',
  'recipient-variables': recipientVars,
};

mailgun.messages().send(envelope, function (error, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

As you would notice all placeholders are populated and `<strong>` tag properly rendered.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have one question; is there a mailgun api to fetch all subscribers; i.e you have hardcoded your recipients array; I would like to create that array programatically; Went through their documentation but couldn't find what I wanted; Actually I found how to fetch list of all who unsubscribed but I want the same for those who have subscribed; Any pointers?

Comment: I'm not sure, didn't have such a task, but they have mailing list api enpoints - https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-mailinglists.html#mailing-lists. Maybe it can help